# Node js stop long process task when Promise reject it

Tags: node.js, promise, node-oracledb

I create a promise function to processing a long-time query task. Some time the task will block for hours. I want set a time out to stop the task. Below is the code.

It can return error message correctly, but it still running connection.execute() for long time before stop. So how can stop it immediately when it return reject message?

Thanks!

```
function executeQuery(connection, query) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    "use strict";
    //long time query
    connection.execute(query, function (err, results) {
        if (err) reject('Error when fetch data');
        else resolve(results);
        clearTimeout(t);
    });

    let t = setTimeout(function () {
        reject('Time Out');
    }, 10);
})


(async () => {
"use strict";
oracle.outFormat = oracle.OBJECT;

try {
    let query = fs.readFileSync("query.sql").toString();
    let results = await executeQuery(connection, query);

    console.log(results.rows);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(`error:${e}`);

}
```

Comment: "*it still running connection.execute()*" - well, you need a way to cancel that operation. Does the library you are using provide that? If no, you're basically out of luck. But at least tell us which library it is, so that we might help you finding a solution.

Comment: Just kill your node task with `process.exit` in the case of an error when you want to abort everything

Comment: @Bergi: Kill your process each time a query fails? That sounds like doing a denial of service on yourself.

Comment: @Bergi: Only oracledb and fs used

Comment: @arboreal84 I was joking :-) But it's really the only way to abort the query if the library doesn't provide any other means.

Comment: Did you try [setting the queue timeout](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#propdbqueuetimeout), or [closing the connection when hitting your custom timeout](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#connectionclose)?

Comment: @Bergi: oracledb.queueTimeout cannot work, as for connection.close(), it return error:

(node:2760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: NJS-032: connection cannot be released because a database call is in progress

Comment: Ah, you will need to call [`connection.break()`](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#break) (not `close`) of course - I'm not familiar with the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can stop it immediately when it return reject message?

According to the docs, you can use [`connection.break`](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#break):

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.execute(query, (err, results) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(results);
        clearTimeout(t);
    });

    const t = setTimeout(() => {
        connection.break(reject); // is supposed to call the execute callback with an error
    }, 10);
})
```

Make sure to also `release` the connection in a `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks for your help, forget that. Already accepted this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this (using `bluebird` promises):

```
var execute = Promise.promisify(connection.execute);

function executeQuery(connection, query) {
   return execute.call(connection, query)
   .timeout(10000)
   .then(function (results) {
      // handle results here
   })
   .catch(Promise.TimeoutError, function (err) {
      // handle timeout error here
   });
   .catch(function (err) {
      // handle other errors here
   });
};
```

If this still blocks, there's a possibility that the database driver you are using is actually synchronous rather than asynchronous. In that case, that driver would be incompatible with the node event loop and you may want to look into another one.

Comment: This is basically exactly what the OP already did with native promises.

Comment: Similar, except that he put a 10 ms timeout rather than a 10 second timeout. Personally I prefer bluebird promises. Doing the equivalent to bluebird promises requires some additional attention to detail and there's a lot of opportunity for human error.

Comment: Yeah, me too. But still, unless you can find such a mistake and point out the detail that works differently, this answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: yes, it works same, still wait a long time to release

Comment: Then there's a problem with the database driver or connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi mentioned, you'll need to use the [`connection.break`](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#break) method.

Given the following function:

```
create or replace function wait_for_seconds(
  p_seconds in number
)
  return number
is
begin
  dbms_lock.sleep(p_seconds);

  return 1;
end;
```

Here's an example of its use:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js');
let conn;
let err;
let timeout;

oracledb.getConnection(config)
  .then((c) => {
    conn = c;

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Timeout expired, invoking break');

      conn.break((err) => {
        console.log('Break finished', err);
      });
    }, 5000);

    return conn.execute(
     `select wait_for_seconds(10)
      from dual`,
      [],
      {
        outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT
      }
    );
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result.rows);

    clearTimeout(timeout);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error in processing', err);

    if (/^Error: ORA-01013/.test(err)) {
      console.log('The error was related to the timeout');
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    if (conn) { // conn assignment worked, need to close
      return conn.close();
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error during close', err)
  });
```

Keep in mind that the `setTimeout` call is just before the execute (because of the return statement). That timeout will start counting down immediately. However, the execute call isn't guaranteed to start immediately as it uses a thread from the thread pool and it may have to wait till one is available. Just something to keep in mind...